# What do I call a curve of drug concentration vs. time if the concentration axis is on a log scale?

Tags: phrase-request, terminology, translation

I have a number of curves of drug concentration vs. time. The time scale, on the horizontal (x) axis, is normal, while the concentration scale is logarithmic (the equidistant notches say 1000 ng/mL, then 10 000 ng/mL, and then 100 000 ng/mL).

In Russian, the curves are called "logarithmicized curves" (**логарифмированные графики** индивидуальных концентраций препарата) in my document because of this. What do I call them in English?

Log-scaled curves?

I looked up **logarithmic curve** - but it's a curve described by a logarithmic equation, while in my document the curves do not look like that at all - they go in zigzags, up and down, not in nice rounded lines in one direction, like logarithmic curves.

Comment: You can call them **logarithmic curves**.

Comment: I think in the pharma studies literature they're known as "log-scale concentration graphs" or "log-concentration graphs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because only one axis has been scaled logarithmically, these plots are referred to as [**semi-logarithmic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-log_plot) plots. Depending on which axis is logarithmicized, it's either a **log-lin plot** (if the y-axis is scaled) or a **lin-log plot** (if the x-axis is scaled). In your case, it's the former.

Note that in English we tend to talk about the *entire graph*, not just a single curve.